# How to prove that a predicate is not hard-core?

Tags: hard-core-predicate

How can I prove that given a predicate $hc$ and a one-way function $f$ that $hc$ is not hard-core?
I was thinking about something like that:

i define $f(x) = (g(x), hc(x))$ that is one-way but $hc$ is not hard-core 'cause it's value is easly reconstructable from the output.

Is it right? How can I actually prove that?

Comment: You must exhibit an efficient algorithm that computes $\mathrm{hc}(x)$ with non-negligible probability when given $f(x)$ (for uniformly random $x$).

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, that $g$ is a OWF and $hc$ is a hardcore predicate of $g$? And your question is why $hc$ is not also a hardcore predicate of $f$ as defined in the question?

Comment: $G$ is a OWF and given the function $f$ that is something like $f(x) = (g(x), hc(x))$ I have to prove that eventhogh $f$ is OWF, $hc$ is not hard core for $f$

Comment: @quaqua: So like given $(g(x), hc(x))$ make a good guess at the value of $hc(x)$?

Comment: @Ry yes, i have to prove it somehow